# How to get image uchar array's actual length opencv2

Tags: opencv

I am trying to use blur an image with a GPU. I shall write my own GPU routine. I am using Opencv2 library for image reading.

I want to access the image array (uchar *), for this I figured out; i can do the following

```
cv::Mat im = imread( 'lena.jpg');
```

I could also figure out that I can get access to the uchar* array --

```
uchar * data = im.data;
```

Now the problem is that, there are padded bytes put into this for efficiency purpose. Which means the size of this array could be more than (or equal to) width*height*channels.

How to get

- a) actual size of this array
- b) variable like widthStep or something    for incrementing
  row-wise??

Answer (score 0):

You need what is called *stride* or *step-width*.
You can access it with `im.step`, as in:

```
cv::Mat im = imread( 'lena.jpg');
uchar * data = im.data;
int stepWidth = im.step;
```

Comment: how about the total length (considering padded bytes) of this uchar* array?

Comment: is this multiplication really necessary. Is there no internal variable which can give this count?

Comment: Seriously? Even if there is, is a single multiplication what's worries you? Check out the cv::Mat docs and header you may find something there.